# Apache HTTP/2 Issues on Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, cloudflare, http2

I have third-party domains pointed to my IP address using A records, and these are configured on the server using a Virtual Host configuration. Here's an example:

```
Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1    

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName clientwebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.clientwebsite.com username.mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/username/html"
    SSLEngine on
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/username.mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/username.mywebsite.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

The content will serve over HTTP/2 only if I use the alias `username.mywebsite.com` and not if I use the client's domain `clientwebsite.com`.

The primary domain for my web server `mywebsite.com` has its NS records with Cloudflare and any URL containing `mywebsite.com` seems to deliver over HTTP/2 just fine - it's any other domain that I'm having a problem with.

Comment: what you describe has nothing to do with the config shown up, your case is probably requests landing in different server or limited by client browser accessing the domain or something in between. Nothing in the config would make httpd discriminate one domain over another in protocol.

Comment: @ezra-s Could this be a CloudFlare issue? All of my domains - with DNS pointing to Cloudflare - work, but DNS existing elsewhere - with only A records pointing - don't want to serve over HTTP/2